# How to open Fragments and Activities in the same function (with drawer layout)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

SO I had this code that allowed me to open fragments through the navigation drawer, but it doesn't allow to open activities:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent); //Doesn't Work
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacts) {
        fragmentClass = Contactos.class; //Works
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        fragmentClass = Sobre.class; /Works
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings){
        Intent settingIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class); //Doesn't Work
        startActivity(settingIntent);
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

So i searched the web for some other solution, and with this new one I can open activities but can't open fragments :|

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //Works
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contacts:
            fragmentClass = Contactos.class; //Doesn't Work
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            fragmentClass = Sobre.class; //Doesn't Work
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class); //Works
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I open both things?
Appreciate any help :)

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are not replacing your fragmment in your second snippet.

2) You are returning **false** for onNavigationItemSelected() method. That's why it doesn't work.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_contacts:
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_content, new Contactos(), "Tag").commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_content, new Sobre(), "Tag").commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class); //Works
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                break;
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
        }
```

If you are going to the MainActivity, make sure you also have a fl_content Layout in MainActivity.

Comment: Edited, check please.

Comment: Yes it worked, can open everything now, thanks. Just having problems with the layout the fragments is show above the main activity

Comment: What problems ? Please explain. You have to wrap all contents of MainActivity in a Relative/Linear/FrameLayout with an id of fl_content to navigate from MainActivity to Fragments in your drawer.

Comment: When i click in the about activity it would show it above the main activity while the main activity was still clickable and visible, but no problem I've fixed it, thanks a lot for the help